Getting 'bash: mysql: command not found' error in docker
In docker container running mysql commands results in a
bash: mysql: command not found error 
mysql --version, or any mysql command; same issue.
Adding mysql-client did not help. Suggestions about adding default-libmysqlclient-dev
apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
Still no able to run mysql.

Please, paste your dockerfile here.

This helped.

For newer MariaDB container versions, the mysql executable does not
exist any more. Replace mysql with mariadb to fix the issue, for
example:

https://techoverflow.net/2023/07/13/how-to-fix-docker-mariadb-mysql-executable-file-not-found-in-path-unknown/
All info online states mysql in command.
For mariadb image it is maridb for any command eg.
docker-compose exec -T mariadb mariadb -uroot -p

Note for the client not installed, mariadb image has it
using this to test:
mariadb --version

Shows client present
mariadb from 11.3.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper


Well, next time write explicitly un the questiin that you use mariadb and not mysql and tag your question solely with mariadb and not with mysql and mariadb

Point noted, but much content still uses mysql, which is why this happens in the first place.
It's a silly mistake once you see it. If it's still considered a bad practice, okay.
p.s. It might be an issue for an experienced stacker, but for a random person searching for help, it might be helpful.
